# How to force a tab bar item to go to the root level of that item whenever its tapped

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm new to iOS and Swift. In my storyboard I've set up a tab bar controller where the right most item is a "More" item that leads to a table view controller embedded in a navigation controller. Each item in the table view (static) goes to a view controller (say "View 1", "View 2", and "View 3").

The default behavior is as follows. Let's say I tap "More". Then I'm looking at the table with cells for "View 1", "View 2", and "View 3". Then let's say I tap "View 1". If I then click a different item in the tab bar controller, and then click "More" again, rather than take me to the table view, it will take me to "View 1" since that's the last thing I tapped when I was last in "More". I'd like the behavior to be that if I tap outside of "More" with another tab bar element, any time I tap "More" again, I want it to **always** take me to the table view, regardless of what I was viewing previously within "More".

Essentially, I want "More" to forget its state or reset its state.

How do I force this to happen?

Comment: When you tap "View 1" from the tableview how you showing the ViewController? Push?

Comment: For the storyboard segue (under "Kind") it reads "Show (e.g. Push)". So I'm guessing push?

Comment: Is bottom bar visible after showing ViewController1?

Comment: Yes. It is visible.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of storyboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will walk you through an example to make sure that it is clear.

Consider that this is the storyboard:

[image]

It has a tabbar view controller connected to:

- A view controller (the one on the top).
- A table view controller which is embeded in navigation controller (the one on the bottom). It has tableview with a static cell, when tap on it, it pushes to another view controller.

So far so good! now, the first view controller class should conforms to [UITabBarControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate) and implements [tabBarController(_:didSelect:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621173-tabbarcontroller) method, as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tabBarController?.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        // im my example the desired view controller is the second one
        // it might be different in your case...
        let secondVC = tabBarController.viewControllers?[1] as! UINavigationController
        secondVC.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    }
}
```

Remark: if you have more that tow view controllers connected to the tabbar view controller, you should apply this code to the first view controller that should appear in the tabbar view controller.

And that's it!

**Output:**

[image]

Cheers up! hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks! Took me a while to get back to this and to figure out how that worked as I'm ordinarily a Rails developer and very new to iOS which is very, very different. But this works perfectly!

Comment: Welcome! you could ask about any non-understandable thing, I tried -as you can see- to make it clear as possible. Glad to help :)

Comment: On the storyboard, which ViewController should have the ViewController class defined above as its class? I am trying to set it to my Tab Bar Controller, but it only accepts TabBarController classes. SOLUTION: I found out that you add the code to the first ViewController on your TabBar.

Answer (score 1):

The code supplied works very well with one exception. If you have multiple tabbar items linked to one view controller then the indexed code tabBarController.viewControllers?[1] will only work on "1". It is possible to have "2" and "3" etc. By adding tabBarController.selectedIndex as the index it will always return back to root for that tabbar item. Below is how I fixed the code. I hope this helps someone:

```
     func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    // im my example the desired view controller is the second one
    // it might be different in your case...
    let secondVC = tabBarController.viewControllers?[tabBarController.selectedIndex] as! UINavigationController
    secondVC.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after making the class confirm to the tabBarController delegate just add this function

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
        }
```